# iOS simulators not showing in Titanium Studio

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, appcelerator-titanium

I recently updated my xcode from version 7.3 to 9.0.1 now in titanium studio simulators are not showing up inside run option. In previous version they were working fine. Also i confirmed that my xcode path in Titanium studio is correct and it shows it as "Installed" when i run some app from run configuration option i get this error.

```
 [ERROR] :  Invalid "--device-id" value "iPhone"
 Available iOS Simulators:
 For help, run: titanium.js help build
```

Please share any clue to solve this issue.
Thanks

Comment: Did you fix this? Getting the same issue now

Answer (score 11):

I had same issue.

Try this command in terminal.

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/
```

Miro